# вывод Console::WriteLine при сложении строк внутри вызова

Tags: c++-cli

Возник один вопросик по *Console::Write()*, как она себя ведёт при такой форме вызова *Console::Write("Строка " + " очень" + "длинная")* , будет ли она выводится одним вызовом?
Поясню в чём проблема, дело в том что я запускаю в ***Node.js*** процесс через ***spawn*** и использую вывод **STDUOT** для получения данных в JSON из программы, и когда я вызывал много *Console::Write* и в конце *Console::WriteLine* иногда я ловил исключение в ***Node.js*** о непредвиденном окончании *JSON*, и судя по логу иногда ***Node.js*** заканчивал чтение **STDUOT** после одной из *Console::Write()*, хотя если запустить программу в консоли то никаких разрывов нету, как я понял между двумя *Console::Write()* иногда происходит какая-то задержка и ***Node.js*** считает что вывод **STDUOT** закончен. Единственное что сейчас не очень устраивает это то что получаются очень длинные и некрасивые *Console::WriteLine()*, поэтому хотелось бы их сделать покороче.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, вы имеете в виду C++/CLI.

В этом предложении

```
Console::Write("Строка " + " очень" + "длинная");
```

сначала вычисляется выражение аргумента, то есть выражение

```
"Строка " + " очень" + "длинная"
```

которое создает одну строку из трех строк посредством их конкатенации, и затем эта результирующая строка выводится на консоль функцией `Write`.

Comment: С удивлением узнал, в C++/CLI (по крайней мере под Visual Studio 2017) `"Строка " + "очень"` имеет тип `System::String^` (в отличие от просто `"Строка очень"`).

Comment: @VladD Когда создаешь консольное приложения, то функция main автоматически определяется следующим образом  int main(array<System::String ^> ^args) :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, просто т.к. пока что Си знаю плохо возник данный вопрос, будет сначала конкатенация или просто вызовет Console::Write для каждой строки.

Comment: @vnn198 Сначала вычисляется выражение аргумента, а затем вызывается функция с передачей ей результирующего значения аргумента. То есть пока аргумент не будет вычислен, функция не вызывается.